# Cypress eslint plugin:cypress/recommended how to ignore "unexpected token ="?

Tags: javascript, eslint, cypress

I'm trying to run eslint on my cypress project but it keeps failing with

> 2:19  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =

Is there a way to ignore the error globally? If I don't run linting my code works fine:

```
class CardPage {
  cardPageURL = "I've removed the url";
  
  visit() {
    cy.visit(this.cardPageURL);
  }
}

export const cardPage = new CardPage();
```

This is my .eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {   extends: ["plugin:cypress/recommended", "prettier"], };
```

Comment: That's nothing to do with Cypress - you'll also need a _parser_ for ESLint that understands class properties.

Comment: Thank you, the linked solution worked fine :)